# Change email boxout text in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Currently, when someone hovers over my picture after receiving a Gmail e-mail from me they see the following:

> I probably wouldn't, tbh.

I no longer want this text to display as it seems a little unprofessional. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that that's derived from the "About me" section of your Google profile.

Simply go to https://myaccount.google.com, click on [Your personal info](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy?pli=1#personalinfo) under "Personal info & privacy" and edit accordingly.